# Regex order when matching single square bracket

Tags: elisp

Hello to all of you,

I have a question regarding a specific regex in Elisp and specifically in Elisp. I'm trying to match a single square bracket and ielm has this:

```
  (string-match "[\]\[]" "[")  ; ===> 0
  (string-match "[\[\]]" "[")  ; ===> nil

  (string-match "[\]\[]" "]")  ; ===> 0
  (string-match "[\[\]]" "]")  ; ===> nil

  (string-match "[\[\]]" "[]") ; ===> 0
  (string-match "[\]\[]" "[]") ; ===> 0
  (string-match "[\]\[]" "][") ; ===> 0
  (string-match "[\]\[]" "][") ; ===> 0
```

Where as with JS, these all return true:

```
'['.match(/[\[\]]/) // ===>['[']
'['.match(/[\]\[]/) // ===>['[']


']'.match(/[\[\]]/) // ===>[']']
']'.match(/[\]\[]/) // ===>[']']

'[]'.match(/[\[\]]/) // ===>['[']
'[]'.match(/[\]\[]/) // ===>['[']
']['.match(/[\[\]]/) // ===>[']']
']['.match(/[\]\[]/) // ===>[']']
```

Here's a regex101: https://regex101.com/r/e8sLXr/1

I don't understand why the order of my square brackets in Elisp matters. I've tried using double backslashes but it doesn't help. Actually, it gives me more nils on these regexes whereas I thought the proper way to escape a backslack in a string for the regex to process was to double it: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Example.html#Regexp-Example

Does anyone know what I'm missing a could help me ?

Cheers,

Thomas

EDIT: grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let's ditch the backslashes.  `[` and `]` are not special to strings(*), and therefore escaping them does not change them. So the following is equivalent, and easier to read:

```
(string-match "[][]" "[")  ; ===> 0
(string-match "[][]" "]")  ; ===> 0
(string-match "[][]" "[]") ; ===> 0
(string-match "[][]" "][") ; ===> 0
(string-match "[][]" "][") ; ===> 0
```

This pattern matches either `]` or `[`, and all the strings being tested have one of those characters at the start; hence we match at position `0` in each case.

Critically, to include a `]` in a character alternative it *must* be the first character. Hence the following did *not* do what you wanted:

```
(string-match "[[]]" "[")  ; ===> nil
(string-match "[[]]" "]")  ; ===> nil
(string-match "[[]]" "[]") ; ===> 0
```

This pattern matches exactly `[]`, because `[[]` is a character alternative matching anything in the set comprising the single-character `[`; and that character alternative is then followed by `]` (which, when it is *not* ending a character alternative, just matches itself).

You will want to read the "character alternative" details at:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Regexp Special` <kbd>RET</kbd>

---

(*) Note also that backslashes are not special to a regexp when they are *within* a character alternative.

Your regexps didn't have any backslashes -- because in double-quoted string format you would have needed to double the backslashes to include those in the regexp -- but if you had done that, and if they were *also* inside the character alternative, it would just mean that a backslash would be one of the characters matched by that set.

e.g. `"[\\]\\[]"` is the regexp `[\]\[]` which matches `\[]`

(Remembering that `]` cannot appear in a character alternative unless it is the *first* character.)